# why side bar dont show in mobile version it disappear?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, adminlte

i am following the code from https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/components/main-sidebar.html it work perfectly in desktop version but when i change into mobile version the side bar is disappeared

```
 <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="index3.html" class="brand-link">
      <img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">AdminLTE 3</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">Alexander Pierce</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <p>
                Starter Pages
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Active Page</p>
                </a>
              </li>
      
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

what should i do ?

Comment: look into the css there are media queries, which detect the screen width, and if its under a certain value then it hides the sidebar

Comment: `@media (max-width: 991.98px) .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar { box-shadow: none!important; }` appears to be responsible for this, at least when I check on the page you linked to (which uses the same sidebar.)

Comment: what should i do now to edit the Adminlte.css file or add the following css in top of my page to replace